# Coordinate alignment of meshes

Tags: mesh, game-engine, coordinates

I have a navigation mesh. In Edit Mode, the coordinate of the first plane of the navigation mesh has a completely different coordinate than that of a cube mesh at the same location. How can I align the coordinates of both these objects?

[image: coordinate of cube mesh]
[image: coordinate of the start cell of navigation mesh]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are looking at coordinates set to **local**. Blender is generating those coordinates based on the distance of the selection from the origin of the object, and not the center of the scene. If you set your coordinates to **global** the numbers will be generated by calculating the distance of the selection from the center pf the scene.

You can set the coordinates to Global by pressing this button.

[image]